# How to search a list with various data types for strings, and if they exist perform an operation on them?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm writing a searching method and the search is case insensitive. I might be searching through lists/dicts with various data types, how do I query that if any strings exist in the list, perform an operation like string.lower() on it? Or, I don't know if this would be more time efficient, search for all instances of strings in a list, and add them case insensitive to a new set, and then search that set for the instance of my string.

Tried the any() implementation but I think I'm doing it wrong, but also not sure that it's the most effective way to do what I'm describing.

```
if isinstance(needle, str): #If needle is a string, convert it to lowercase and if haystack has any strings in it, convert them to lowercase too.
            needle = needle.lower()

            if any(str in haystack):

                for item in haystack:

                    if type(item) == str in haystack:
                        item = item.lower()
```

Above code returns a 
`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not type.`
Which I don't really understand, as I was hoping for it to determine that there's at least one instance of a string in the haystack, then to perform the lower() function on it.

Comment: First of all you have to establish the expected behavior. You said that you want to search the strings within various data types, but you did not provide what types exactly they are. You said that one type could be dict, but dictionaries has keys and values, what would be used to be compared with the searching word; keys or values? What is the expected result of the function? Boolean indicating if match was found? List of matched words? Count of them?

Comment: What do you expect `if any(str in haystack)` to do?  `str` is a function.

Comment: @Nf4r - I'm assuming compatible data types. So if the needle is an str and the haystack is a dictionary type, it will return -1 stating incompatible types. The haystack would have to be dict.keys() or dict.values() for example. In one instance it just wants to check if needle exists in haystack, if so return 1. In another, it wants to count the number of needles in haystack, I was going to handle those cases later.

Comment: @JohnGordon You're totally right! I forgot str is a typecasting function in Python. How would I write a check to determine if there are any str data types within a given object/list? That's what I'm trying to check.

Comment: `if any(type(x) is str for x in haystack)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, '1', 'A']
my_list = [e.lower() if isinstance(e, str) else e for e in my_list ]
```

instead of lower method, you can apply any function that works with strings

Comment: This works, thank you! But say it's a very long list and I want to check if there any strings in it before I start trying to do things to it. How do I implement my any() check above? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It would be pretty similar: `if any(isinstance(item, str) for item in my_list)`